# How to let-bind multiple variables conditional on X?

Tags: let-binding

**Q:** how can I `let`-bind multiple variables conditional on *x*?

Assume that I have three variables, `a`, `b`, and `c`, that I want
to `let`-bind conditional on some other `x`.  How do I do that
concisely and idiomatically?

Here's an example that works, but is repetitive and error-prone:

```
(let ((a (if t 1 4))
      (b (if t 2 5))
      (c (if t 3 6)))
  (list a b c))                         ; => (1 2 3)
```

Here's another example that works, but the use of `setq` feels
both repetitive and inelegant:

```
(let (a b c)
  (if t
      (setq a 1
            b 2
            c 3)
    (setq a 4
          b 5
          c 6))
  (list a b c))                         ; => (1 2 3)
```

Here's an example that *doesn't* work, because the variables fall
outside the scope of the `let`-binding:

```
(if t
    (let ((a 1)
          (b 2)
          (c 3)))
  (let ((a 4)
        (b 5)
        (c 6)))
  (list a b c))                         ; => nil
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a reasonable way is to collect all the values into a list and then use a destructuring bind, e.g., `pcase-let`:

```
(pcase-let ((`(,a ,b ,c)
             (if t (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))))
  (list a b c))
```

or `cl-multiple-value-bind` (a bit cleaner than the pcase version since it is specialised to lists, and only allows a single binding clause):

```
(cl-multiple-value-bind (a b c)
    (if t (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))
  (list a b c))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no idiomatic way to do it, IMO. Do what you like.

If you want to be sure to test the condition only once that you are currently retesting, then here is another possibility, where I've used function `my-test` instead of your vague "`x`" or "`X`" (which doesn't seem to actually be referenced in the code you show, which uses `t` instead):

```
(let* ((test  (my-test))
       (a     (if test 1 4))
       (b     (if test 2 5))
       (c     (if test 3 6)))
  (list a b c))
```

Or if you care about the bindings of `a`, `b`, and `c` not being sequential:

```
(let ((test  (my-test)))
  (let ((a  (if test 1 4))
        (b  (if test 2 5))
        (c  (if test 3 6)))
     (list a b c))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider storing your results in a list, and then access them using simple list operations such as `car`, `cdr`, or `nth`. This technique is showcased in the following code sample. While using `cl-multiple-value-bind` might enhance readability for some, the example below directly leverages fundamental list features.

```
(defun asciify-line-or-region ()
  "Transform the selected region or current line's content to ASCII."
  (interactive)
  (let ((begin-end
         (if (use-region-p)
             (cons (region-beginning) (region-end)) ; If region is selected, use its start and end.
           (cons (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))) ; Otherwise, use current line's start and end.
    (call-process-region (car begin-end) (cdr begin-end) "iconv" t t nil "--to-code=ASCII//TRANSLIT")))
```

This method is straightforward and taps into the core list manipulation capabilities of Emacs Lisp.